# web reference user not authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asmx

Asp.net web application using the API with c# visual studio 12 MVC application. I have successfully added the web reference and I have all of the correct info in the call from the svc.ContactList_Retrieve call from the web reference "CatalystCRMWEbservice", and it is all in the right order, but I keep getting this error message

> soapException was unhandled by user code, An exception of type
>   'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Services.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Server was unable to process request. ---> ERROR: No synchronization required at this time.

Here is the code for the home controller.

```
using pearlsquickalystapp.bc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace pearlsquickalystapp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
     [HttpGet]

        public ActionResult List()
        {

            CatalystCRMWebservice svc = new CatalystCRMWebservice();

            bool more = false;
            int startNumber = 0;

            ContactRecord[] users = svc.ContactList_Retrieve(
            "username", "password", siteId, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10), ref startNumber,
            ref startNumber, ref more);

            return View("List", users);

        }

    }
}
```

Here is the code for the List view.

```
@model pearlsquickalystapp.bc.ContactRecord []

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
}

<h2>List</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ContactRecord</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.entityId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.entityId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.entityId)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.externalId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.externalId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.externalId)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.emailAddress, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.emailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.emailAddress)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.contactTitle, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.contactTitle)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.contactTitle)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.deleted, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.deleted)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.deleted)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fullName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fullName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fullName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.username, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.username)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dateOfBirth, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dateOfBirth)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dateOfBirth)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.createDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.createDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.createDate)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastUpdateDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lastUpdateDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastUpdateDate)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.customerType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customerType)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customerType)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.industryType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.industryType)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.industryType)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.leadSourceType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.leadSourceType)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.leadSourceType)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ratingType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ratingType)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ratingType)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MasterOptIn, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MasterOptIn)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MasterOptIn)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And here is the requested Soap data code

```
    POST /CatalystWebService/CatalystCRMWebservice.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: pearlssportsshop.worldsecuresystems.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/CatalystDeveloperService/CatalystCRMWebservice 
/ContactList_Retrieve"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org  
/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
<ContactList_Retrieve xmlns="http://tempuri.org/CatalystDeveloperService/CatalystCRMWebservice">
  <username>string</username>
  <password>string</password>
  <siteId>int</siteId>
  <lastUpdateDate>dateTime</lastUpdateDate>
  <recordStart>int</recordStart>
  <moreRecords>boolean</moreRecords>
  </ContactList_Retrieve>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

I'm not sure if this is enough info.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: BTW, did we really need to see the entire view?

Comment: John, thanks for the reply. I am using asp.net. I included the entire view because I figured too much info was better than not enough info.

Comment: Ok, I get it, the web service is written in asmx.

Comment: Actually, too much info is likely to cause your question to be ignored. We can always ask for more information if we need it.